# <output> is going to 12 decimal places instead of 2

Tags: html, forms

I'm trying to get the below outputs of this form to limit the outcome to 2 decimal place as it's a currency.

I've tried another suggestion by adding an onchange event but it's not working. Any suggestions?

```
<form oninput="retVal.value = pavVal.value - (pavVal.value * pavCAT.value),salvage.value=pavVal.value * pavCAT.value,  retPrevVal.value = ((pavVal.value *0.8) * (1 - pavCAT.value))">
        <table> 
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="pavVal"><b>PAV:</b></label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="pavVal">
                </td>
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="pavCAT" ><b>CAT:</b></label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="pavCAT"  value="0.28" >
                    <label for="0.28" style="padding-right:30px; width:50%;" >Category N (28%)</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="pavCAT" value="0.2" >
                    <label for="0.2" style="padding-right:30px; width:50%;">Category S (20%)</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="pavCAT"  value="0.05" >
                    <label for="0.05" style="padding-right:30px; width:50%;">Category B (5%)</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="retVal"><b>Retention Value:</b></label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <output name="retVal" for="pavVal pavCAT" onchange="setTwoNumberDecimal()"></output>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="retPrevVal"><b>Salvage Value:</b></label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <output name="salvage" for="pavVal pavCAT" onchange="setTwoNumberDecimal()"  ></output>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="retPrevVal"><b>If Previous TL:</b></label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <output name="retPrevVal" for="pavVal pavCAT"></output>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: unclear how an html element would limit decimal numbers. There are no change events so what you need to do is alter whatever is setting the content of this element.

Comment: I've changed the code to be my whole code :)